# Explain why there is no subring of $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

This 2 mark question has been bothering me for a while because I think I know how its done but I am unsure how to explain it.

I am aware that if $\mathbb{Z}_{m} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ then $m = n$.  Furthermore, since $19$ is a prime number then the only subrings of $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$ are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$.

Therefore we know that $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$.  However, how do I show that $\{0\}$ is not isomorphic either?

Thank you

Comment: How many elements does it have?

Comment: I think the exercise meant proper subring i.e a non trivial subring. check again your source

Comment: You mean how to show that the ring with $1$ element is not isomorphic to one with $6$ elements? Though also note that in most texts, subrings are required to contain the original unity and so these rings have just themselves as subring.

Comment: @GuyFabrice I've checked the source and all it said was "subring".   What do you mean by unity?

Comment: @user432533 For "unity", or "multiplicative identity", see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135046/which-subrings-s-of-mathbb-z-ncontains-a-multiplicative-identity-that-is).

Comment: Can  a group of order $19$ have a subgroup of order $6$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No it cannot! Does that mean it cannot be isomorphic?

Comment: @user432533 A subring has to be a subgroup of the original ring's additive group.

Answer (score 0):

Every subring of $R=\mathbb{Z}/n$ is an ideal, see 
[Show every subring of ring $\Bbb Z_n$ is ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035254/show-every-subring-of-ring-bbb-z-n-is-ideal/2035307). 
Since for $n=19$, $R$ is a field, every ideal is $0$ or $R$. Both cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/6$ for cardinality reasons.

Comment: Note that every subring is an additive subgroup. Then use Lagrange.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to say.  What do you mean by cardinality reasons?

Comment: Two finite isomorphic groups must have the same cardinality, i.e.,the same number of elements. But $6\neq 1$ and $6\neq 19$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\Bbb Z_{19}$ had such a subring isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$, it's additive group would be a subgroup of the additive group of $\Bbb Z_{19}$.

By Lagrange, we would then have $6\mid 19$, contradiction.